# View App Check Token in Chrome (Flutter web)

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web, firebase-app-check

Is it possible, to view the app check token used by my flutter web app?

When I check the *inspect* page of chrome, there is no `X-Firebase-AppCheck` header.

I thought there was supposed to be one, or am I looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score -1):

You can find it in Developer Tools -> Network
You will need to pick one of the requests that needs that token (for example a call to firestore)
Once you pick one look in the Headers of the request

Comment: I already tried that, there is no app check token there